# querystring using eval for hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I have the following line of code in .aspx

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hpViewProfile" NavigateUrl='<%# "CompanyProfile.aspx?companycode="+b64encode(Eval("Companycode").ToString())+"&cat="+b64encode(Eval("category").ToString()) %>' CssClass="smallbt" runat="server"><span class="icon_view"></span>View Profile</asp:HyperLink>
```

when I am clicking on view profile i am getting the output(url) as
dubaiexporters.com/CompanyProfile.aspx?companycode=MzU5Mw==&cat=QXV0b21vdGl2ZQ==

Instead of that i want the http://dubaiexporters.com/CompanyProfile.aspx?companycode=(code from database) & cat=(category name from db)..
 i dont know why i am not getting code and category name in the url after clicking on view profile...

Comment: Maybe because you seem to base 64 encode is yourself? `b64encode`

Comment: actually i removed b64encode....and company code and category name got displayed in url but at the same time, the contents of the page(companyprofile.aspx) got disappeared i.e. after removing b64encode...